# BitTorrent IPv4 - IPv6 interaction

Tags: ipv6, bittorrent, ipv4

My ISP only provides me with an IP4 adress, but Deluge (Torrent-Client) lists IP6 adresses in the peers tab. How does this work? I thought to not be able to communicate with IP6 devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is because of the automatic IPv6-in-IPv4 Teredo tunneling in Windows. It not reliable for normal use but as BitTorrent distributes the load across many connection anyway some of those Teredo connections might actually work :-)

Windows systems only try to use Teredo when connecting explicitly to an IPv6 address when no other IPv6 access is available. Teredo won't be used when connecting to a hostname instead of an explicit address.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some form of IPv6 tunneling configured (e.g. Teredo tunneling). Check `ifconfig` (`ipconfig` on Windows) to be sure.